# How to make an email validation inside a partial with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm trying to show a message like this (my input is called "txtEmail")

```
<span ng-show="frm.txtEmail.$error.email">Email is wrong!</span>
```

it's inside a partial, the html container has a form called "frm".

But for some reason it doesn't work, it just work if the form is inside of the partial.

I'm using AngularJS on ASP .Net MVC project.

**Edited**

I don't have custom validation and I've tried with $invalid.

When I execute the app I can see the html complete with the "frm" form but it doesn't work.

When I use it inside a dummy form

```
<form  name="foo">
                <span ng-show="foo.txtEmail.$error.email">Email is wrong!</span>
```

.
.
.
    
it works.

Comment: It could be that you are accessing it incorrectly. Are you setting some custom validation flags? If not have you tried checking the element itself for validity? (E.G. frm.txtEmail.$invalid )

Answer (score 0):

Make sure partial containing `span` is inside the form element `frm`

Comment: I believe as long as the form and span tag are contained in the same scope the location doesn't really matter since the span tag has access to the frm object.

Comment: @Matt The location does matter if you want access the correct scope. Go to this http://plnkr.co/edit/1r9NvuQoO8t1pDdicAK7?p=preview and empty the text box. The element outside the form would not have access to form.

Comment: That is because the controller is specified on the form, I anticipated that it was attached to an outer div tag or something higher than the form itself. That miscommunication was my bad -- in the case of your example you are correct and nothing outside the form has access to that scope by traditional means without a method of broadcasting/binding.

Answer (score 0):

Try following methods:

**Method 1**

Replace `frm` form name by `someObj.frm`

**Method 2**

Wrap included content into ng-form such as:

```
<ng-form name="includedFrm">
<span ng-show="frm.includedFrm.txtEmail.$error.email">Email is wrong!</span>
</ng-form>
```